# $X \subset C^0[0,1] $,closed, bounded, equicontinuous $\implies $ $\forall g \in \! X \quad \exists h \in X$ s.t.$ \int_0^1 h \geq \int_0^1 g$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I took a Real Analysis class and have been teaching myself some basic functional analysis. I am really unsure of how to prove the following:

Let $X \subset C^0[0,1]$ that is closed, bounded, and equicontinuous. Prove that $\ \exists h \in X$ s.t. $ \int_0^1 h \geq \int_0^1 g$ for all g in X

I was thinking about possibly trying to use something involving Lipschitz.

Comment: Take h = g ! I assume you meant $\exists h$ s.t. $\forall g$, didn't you ?

Comment: oops. you are correct that is what I meant. Let me change that

Comment: Are you sure the statement is like this? It seems trivial to me.

Comment: Ok, now have you ever heard about Ascoli Theorem ? (also known as Arzela-Ascoli Theorem )

Comment: That's (almost) exactly the theorem. Precisly, it says that any familly of function from a compact metric space to a complete metric space, which is equicontinuous and such that the closure of th set of values taken at a point by the familly of function is compact, is relatively compact. Here you have a bit more, the familly of function is globally bounded instead of pointwise bounded

Comment: It is compact and metric so from any subsequence you can extract a convergent one. Now which sequence would you like to look at ?

Comment: Yes. The point is that $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ with $||.||_{\infty}$ is a metric space, whose points are functions. Saying that a subset $X$ it is compact is equivalent to say that from any sequence of points of $X$(which actually are function !) you can extract a convergent subsequence (convergent in the sence that the distance $d(f_n,f) = ||f_n - f||_{\infty} $ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity for a certain $f \in X$). Is it clearer ?

Comment: Don't be sorry, and let's try to find out where you don't understand. Can you do something if i tell you look at a sequence $f_n \in X$ such that $\int{f_n}$ goes to $\sup_{g\in X}{\int{g}}$ ?

Comment: That is almost obvious. $A = \sup_{g\in X}{\int{g}} \in \mathbb{R} $  By definition of $\sup$, $\forall \epsilon$, $\exists f_{\epsilon} \in X$ such that $ A-\epsilon \leq \int{f_{\epsilon}} \leq A $. Now I let you put the pieces together

Comment: I don't understand why you deleted all your comments and are trying to delete the contents of your question. I rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of using the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, which states that if $Y$ is compact Hausdorff, and $C(Y)$ is the space of continuous functions on $X$, then given a subset $X \subset Y$, $X$ is compact if and only if it is closed, **pointwise** bounded, and equicontinuous. If you meant pointwise bounded above, then you get from Arzela-Ascoli that $X$ is compact.

The norm on $X$ is the uniform norm. The norm is continuous on compact $X$, so achieves a maximum on $X$, say $M$. Can you use this to pick $h$?

Comment: This is the right idea. Bounded will mean bounded in the uniform norm (this implies pointwise bounded) and you maximize the functional $g \mapsto \int g$ on $X$ which is continuous with respect to the uniform norm.